# Wordpress Sitemap for MSSQL

Tags: seo, google, wordpress, blog

does anyone know a proper sitemap plugin for wordpress that works with ms sql?

Comment: This might be more appropriate in the wordpress SE: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: there is a wordpress stack exchange site? didn't know... thanks... some body should close this...

Comment: Closing as requested.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.xml-sitemaps.com/ has a good tool for making sitemaps.. It doesnt require a DB, so mssql or mysql it does not care.